# Headset microphone not working while internal built-in microphone works in Dell inspiron 5759 running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, dell, alsa, microphone

I have a Dell Inspiron 5759 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. My laptop's internal in-built speakers and microphone works well. But when I plug in my headset(3.5 mm 4-pole [TRRS]), headset output audio works fine, but headset microphone is not working.

[image: Sound settings]

As you can see in my sound setting, where there is some response in headset microphone, but it's actually a static noise when I tried to record it.

Please find my **[ALSA Information Script](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=6a969401f6666f2245d3c6d72883e6237cc38980)** in case you find it useful to help.

Also find the output for the command `lspci -knn | grep -i audio -A2`

[image: lspci -knn | grep -i audio -A2]

And output for the command `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec`

[image: cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec]

PS: I'm new to Linux and this microphone issue drives me crazy. I tried a lot of solution and finally came here for help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the headset attached. USB Bluetooth 3.5 jack?

Comment: Hi @David. It's attached using 3.5 jack.

Comment: A single jack or 2? If it uses only one then it needs an adapter to be able to use both ports on the laptop to use sound and mic.

Comment: It's a single jack. As mentioned in my laptop specs, "One headset (headphone and microphone combo) port". My headset contains an in-built microphone. Do I still need an adapter?

Comment: So you need the adapter so it plugs into both sound and mic on the laptop. Sounds like you are using a headset made for a phone.

Comment: Could you provide a link to an adapter as I have limited knowledge on that?

Comment: Just do a google search

Comment: But I'm using 3.5 mm 4-pole (TRRS) headset. Do I still need a adapter? https://obrazki.elektroda.pl/9979964500_1496244822.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the headset microphone is working, and it turned out to be a hardware issue in my laptop's IO board. I disassembled my laptop and cleaned my IO board, and my microphone issue is solved. Thank you!